# How to retrieve the comment and LIKE count of a facebook post

Tags: facebook, web-applications, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to execute following FQL and the result is always an empty XML

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT post_id, comments.count FROM stream where post_id = 167995709886177

```
<fql_query_response list="true"/>
```

This is the post and it has lot of comments and LIKEs
http://www.facebook.com/ryanleslie/posts/167995709886177

Please help

Answer (score 1):

@Anz just go through facebook developer section. all your doubt solve their

Comment: I posted the question here cos I couldn't find a solution ther!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a URL like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/**100002725117360_142921995808637**?access_token=154407880175|16a3d55d6e4be468d6a131bc.1-100002735407608|IhahmvIUsur7GuZ45rxRj3boXtE

The bolded id (100002725117360_142921995808637) is the ID of the post.  The part before the underscore is the user id of the person on whose wall the post appears, and the part after is probably the ID you are using in the example.

This will give you everything you need -- comments, likes, etc.  If you want even narrower info, you can do that with URLs like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/**100002725117360_142921995808637/likes**?access_token=154407880175|16a3d55d6e4be468d6a131bc.1-100002735407608|IhahmvIUsur7GuZ45rxRj3boXtE

Note: this is a test user account, so I'm not exposing anyone's private info here.